# Surface integral over a plane

Tags: integration

> [image: The question's picture!]

I've looked over numerous surface integral questions, but I just cannot understand how the projection works.

I'm given $A: (x+y^2)i - (2x)j + (2yz)k$.

$S$ is the surface of the plane $2x+y+2z=6$ in the first octant.

How do we know on which plane the projection will work best and how the limits of integration work. The method I've been taught is:

$\iint A \cdot \hat{n} \  ds$, where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal vector perpendicular to the surface, and $ds = \frac{dx\,dy}{\hat{n} \cdot \hat{k}}$, if the projection is onto the $xy$ plane.

Can someone please solve this question with this method and clear my confusion on limits and where and how to take the projection.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you need the surface area? In that case you would not need any vector field. My guess is that you have to find the flux of the given field across the given surface, $\int \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{dS}$.

Comment: I'm just given a function A which is stated above. I myself expected it to be a vector field, but it seems I am wrong. I do need to find the surface area.

Comment: But the method you mention involves the vector field $A$, which you definitely do not need to find the surface area. Observe that your surface is just a triangle in the first octant.

Comment: I've given the picture of the question above. Please check it and clear my confusions. It seems I'm also confused b/w flux and the surface area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by finding the unit normal to your surface $F(x,y,z)=2x+y+2z-6=0$ (which is clearly constant in this case):
$$
\mathbf{n}=\frac{\nabla F}{\|\nabla F\|}=(2/3,1/3,2/3).
$$
Given that it is a graph, we can use $x$ and $y$ as parameters. Next, you find the dot product $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{n}$, in terms of $x,y$:
$$
\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{n}=2(x+y^2)/3-2x/3+4y(-x-y/2+3)/3=4y-\frac{4xy}{3}.
$$
Finally, your area element is $dS=\frac{3}{2}dxdy$ (see the surface area computation). You then compute the double integral
$$
\frac{3}{2}\iint_\Delta(4y-\frac{4xy}{3})\,dxdy
$$
where $\Delta$ is as before, the triangle cut out by the line $2x+y-6=0$ in the first quadrant:
$$
\frac{3}{2}\iint_\Delta(4y-\frac{4xy}{3})\,dxdy=\frac{3}{2}\int\limits_0^3\left(\int\limits_0^{-2x+6}\left(4y-\frac{4xy}{3}\right)\,dy\right)\,dx=\frac{3}{2}\int\limits_0^3\left(\left(4-\frac{4x}{3}\right)\int\limits_0^{-2x+6}y\,dy\right)\,dx
$$
$$
=\frac{3}{2}\int\limits_0^3\left(-\frac{8}{3}x^3+24x^2-72x+72\right)\,dx
$$
which is a simple polynomial integral. The final result is $81$.

Comment: Oh, you separated x and y when integrating. That really helped me. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: The answer by your calculations is 54, although the answer is 108.

Comment: when integrating, did you not use ds=dxdy/n.k ?

Comment: I used your methods to do my own calculation, but my answer is -81. Why is it negative?

Comment: You just have to reverse your normal (change the sign) they do not specify the orientation of your surface

Comment: There is a factor $3/2$ missing for the surface element then you get $81$. This factor appears in the computation of the area. I will correct it in my answer. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Do u know any book or online resources which describes this method.I just can't find this in my textbooks...

Comment: @Aladdin What I did is pretty standard. You can find it in any of the standard textbooks (Stewart's, Thomas', etc.) or in better books like Spivak's or Apostol's. What textbooks are you using?

Comment: I am using vector calculus by Jerold E Marsden

Answer (score 0):

Your surface is the graph of $z=f(x,y)=-x-y/2+3$. The surface area is the double integral
$$
A=\iint\sqrt{1+(\partial z/\partial x)^2+(\partial z/\partial y)^2}dxdy
$$
Over the projection on the $XY$ plane which is a triangle. The integrand is just a constant,
$$
A=3/2\iint_\Delta dx dy
$$
Where $\Delta$ Is the projection. $\Delta$ is a triangle of area $9$ therefore your surface area is $27/2$

Comment: My answer above is for the area. Your question is about finding a flux

Comment: Can you please give me the answer on the flux as well? Thanks a lot!